# Django i18n setlang view gives Error 404

Tags: django, localization, internationalization, translation

I am trying to translate a django app using the built in i18n. I have already marked the text to be translated and created and compiled the language files (`.po/.mo`) according to the tutorial and with out errors. I've also changed the `USE_I18N` to true in the settings file and added the following line into the urls.py as the tutorial instructed:

```
(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

I also defined a list of allowed languages in the settings.py, as instructed by the tutorial.

then i created a new page html template and copied in the code the tutorial gave for a language select page:

> ```
> <form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
>  {% csrf_token %}
>  <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
>  <select name="language">
>   {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
>   {% for language in languages %}
>    <option value="{{ language.code }}">{{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})</option>
>   {% endfor %}
>  </select>
>  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
> </form>
> ```

that page works perfectly too, but when i click on "Go", it tells me there was an error loading the page:

```
Failed to load resource:http://localhost:8000/i18n/setlang/ 
the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

I tried changing the redirect by replacing the variable with the link, but that gave me the same result. I tried changing the form action path and the urls.py in case there was some double naming, which gave me the same error.

I have been reading through the tutorial and the readmes, as well as some of the i18n files and can't seem to find a reason for it not to work, and i would really appreciate an answer. thankyou

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you used the correct urls.py, i.e. the one in your project root, and not in a subdirectory?

What happens if you change it to:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
...
(r'^i18n/', lambda x: HttpResponse("Test")),
```

Can you go to `http://localhost:8000/i18n/` after that?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, although i had just found another solution 2 min before reading your post. I went around the included django code and included a direct link to the view in urls.py, although i had to rename it and take out the slashes:
`url(r'^setlang',  'django.views.i18n.set_language'),
`<form action="setlang" method="post">`(select_language.html)
thank you again for your efforts.