# Language Translation in Django using i18n

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, multilingual

I create multilingual flatpages. i want to translate the content according to the language which i select.
i refer this code
[Django i18n setlang view gives Error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10898614/django-i18n-setlang-view-gives-error-404?answertab=active)
When i select the language the post method is call i18n/setlang & again comes into same page, but the content is not change.
Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

**settings**

```
gettext = lambda s: s

LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English'),),
    ('no', gettext('Norwegian'),),
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'multilingual.context_processors.multilingual',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

**template**

```
{% load i18n %}
 <form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
   <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{ redirect_to }}" />
   <select name="language">
      {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
      {% for language in languages %}
       <option value="{{ language.code }}">{{ language.name }} ({{ language.code }})</option>
      {% endfor %}
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>


 **view.py**
 def index(request):
    return render_to_response('flatpages/index.html', locals(),   context_instance=RequestContext(request))

**index.html**
 {% block content %}
 {% load i18n %}
     <h1>{{ flatpage.title }}</h1>
     Language Code:{{ LANGUAGE_CODE}}<br>
     {% trans "Hello" %}<br>
     {% trans "Home" %}<br>
     {{ flatpage.content }}
 {% endblock content %}
```

In above code i use the
url (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
This means when form is submitted it call the method set_language from django's i18n.py file.

I check that method, in that method "check_for_language(lang_code) returns false"
that why the session variable not set.

Can anybody please tell me why this not set?
There will any changes in setting to set path of locale.
I created locale folder in my project folder.

Comment: Have you followed the django documentation and setup the appropriate Locale middleware? In other words, post your relevant settings, form and view please

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I add the code which i use for language translation. Can you please refer & tell me what should i done wrong?

Comment: In view i just render the default flatpage template file.

Comment: I didn't understand how should i accept the post i18n/setlang response in view?

Comment: If you know any data regarding this can you please tell me?

Comment: I write this view for simple page i.e home page.

Comment: Uhm the view that handles your form at /i18n/setlang/ ?

Comment: I didn't write such view. Can you please tell what it should contain?

Comment: Errr then what are you expecting to process the form? Have a look at the internationalization topic at djangoproject.com

Comment: Are you sure that the page is not being cached? (If page is being cached at first visit, it will be cached in the first language. Then if you reload it with the second language, the language will be set, but the page will be loaded from cache, in first language.) What happens if you navigate other pages after changing language?

Comment: When i navigate to other pages, the content will be still in previous language. The content not change to new langauge.

Answer (score 0):

404 means you're calling for a page that doesn't exist. By your comments I understand you don't have an endpoint at `/i18n/lang/`.

Example:

```
from django.views.i18n import set_language

url('^i18n/setlang/$', set_language)
```

However if you want some custom behaviour so have a look at set_language and create your own implementation

Comment: I didn't get the 404 error. The the post method method call correctly. I just want to get the post response as the language code & reload same page with that language.

Comment: If you didn't get a 404 then really, what's your view code at **/i18n/lang/** because there must be something there ;-)

Comment: i use this url:  url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),  which directly calls the django i18n file,  which contain the set_language() method

Comment: @Meenakshi , could you please share your solution?

Comment: @Meenakshi, Please share your solution. I have a same problem.